# How to calculate rental income of an appreciating property?

Tags: recursive-algorithms

I'm trying to calculate the total rental income I might receive over 25 years. The rent is 5% of the property value, which is initially £300k. If the property itself increases in value by 3% per year, how much total rent will I have received after 25 years.

I'm trying to do this in 'Numbers' on a Mac, so if you can provide a function I can use for that, that'd be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) with starting value $5\% \text { of } 300=15$ and ratio of terms $1.03$, so the sum is $15\frac {1-1.03^{25}}{1-1.03}$

Comment: What notation have you used? I don't know how to read your answer. Is it latex or something?

Comment: I did write it in $\LaTeX$, but it is the same notation used in all math-powers and fractions.  If you look at the Wikipedia article you will see the same.